# How to use Memory Route In React Js ? What is exact method to use route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have made use of react js memory router as below in my App.js -

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import  './Components/Login'
import Login from './Components/Login';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Welcome from './Components/Welcome';
import{MemoryRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
function App() {
  const state = useSelector(state => state.allReducers)
  console.log(state.user.isValid);
  
  return (    
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact="/" component={Login}></Route>
          <Route exact="/" component={Welcome}></Route>
        </Switch>
    <div className="App">
     {state.user.isValid==false ||state.user.isValid== undefined  ? <Login></Login> : <Welcome name={state.user.userName}></Welcome>} 
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

But this is displaying my `Login` component twice on the screen.

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: the first is from `<Route exact="/" component={Login}></Route>` and the second from `<Login></Login>` inside the ternary. Not sure what you're actually trying to achieve here (and your routes are certainly wrong as @GabrielLupu says)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route configs should be:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/" component={Welcome} exact={true} />
</Switch>
```

`exact` should be a boolean value. And it'll tell the router only render the route match exactly with the URL. It means, the router only renders the `Welcome` component when the user stays at `/`.

But after you changed to my suggestion, you still see 2 login forms if you navigate to `/login`. Because the `div.app` will be rendered for every route :D

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same route for both components: `<Route exact="/"...` so React will show you both. Use different routes for each component. And your syntax is a bit wrong. Like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/"><Welcome /></Route>
  <Route exact path="/login"><Login /></Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: while the components should certainly have different routes, React Router won't show both in this case - it will just show the first.